# Passing parameters to browser.get - protractor

Tags: protractor

### Context :

- `@angular/cli 7.3.9`
- `protractor 5.4.0`
- `karma 4.0.0`

### Issue :

How do `protractor`'s `browser` method `get` takes url parameters query ?

`browser.get('${browser.baseUrl}?p=2')` is redirecting to `http://localhost:4200/&p=2` instead of `http://localhost:4200&p=2`.

When i supress last character of `browser.baseUrl`, the redirected url is `http://localhost:420/&p=2` ...

Any idea ?

### Edit :

I tried edit `protractor.conf.js` by adding `baseUrl` but i does not change anything ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set a `baseUrl` in the config file, then there is no need to add `browser.baseUrl` in the get method, you can omit it.

For instance, in the config you have:

```
exports.config = {
   // ...

   baseUrl: 'https://github.com/search',
}
```

In the test, you can just add the query parameters like this:

```
it('should open the URL with the query parameter', async () => {
  await browser.get('?q=test'); // will open the 'https://github.com/search?q=test' page
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, i just followed the correct use of `baseUrl` you are showing. Unfortunately protractor is still adding a trailing slash at the end of the base url before query params like `https://github.com/search/?q=test` ...
I double checked the `protractor.conf.js`, there is no slash at the end of the `baseUrl`